# How do I wait for a query to return results and then assign to json array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using *node/express/mongoose/mongodb*, and I have a collection of "packets."  the users can individually set the status of the "packets," and I trying to show them the list of all the packets, and show them the status that they set for the packet.  I've been working on this for a few days and can't make it work right.

What I think has to happen is that I have to query the first list, and then loop through an array of the results and add the results, if there is results to the first packet.

It seems to be either a closure problem or a problem with just the timing to return results.  No matter what I've figured out to try works.

Thanks,

Here's where I am:

```js
 var Packet = mongoose.model('Packet', new Schema({
  id: ObjectId,
  userId: String,  //whom originally posted packet
  courseId: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Course', index: true, 
            required: true }, 
  content: {type: String, index: true}, 
  status: String,
  date: {type: Date, default: Date.now}, 
  mostRecentEdit: {type: Date, default: Date.now} 
}));

var History = mongoose.model('History', new Schema({
 id: ObjectId,
 userId: String,
 status: {type: String, index: true, required: true, default: 1},
 courseId: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Course', required: true },
 clickCounter: {type: Number, default: 1},
 packetId: {type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Packet', required: true },
 date: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
}));
app.get('/api/packets/:_id', stormpath.groupsRequired(['Paid']), 
stormpath.getUser, function(req, res, next){
    var status;
    var pack;
    var newStatus;
try{
   Packet.find({courseId: req.params._id})
         .exec( function(err, packets){  
             pack = packets;
             for (i = 0; i < pack.length; i++){
                var promise = History.findOne({
                    packetId: pack[i]._id,
                   userId: req.user.email
                   })
                  .select('status')
                  .exec( function(err, package){ 
                      if(package == null){
                         status =  1
                      } else {
                        status = package.status;      
                      };
                   newStatus = status
              });
              promise.then(pack[i].status = newStatus);
         };
        res.json(pack)}
    });
  }catch(err){
    next(err);
  };
 });
```

Comment: Would you care to show the schema definitions for the models `Packet` and `History`? From observation it seems like you could use the populate method or aggregation framework's `$lookup` to get the desired results, just need to confirm with your models` schema definition.

Comment: thanks chridam.   aggregation will help me out.

Comment: By the way, what's your MongoDB server version?

Comment: 2.2.5 mongodb version